# Landing page and development site

Tags: seo, googlebot, search-results

We currently have a Landing page for our website with no navigation or links only a contact form. However, I am adding content to other pages on the LIVE site that only I can get to for now.

Will Google be able to index these pages when currently there is no way from the root/homepage to get to them, no links/path for the bots?

Eventually, the homepage of course will have a lot of content and I will switch out the frontpage from the landing template to the final homepage template.

Is there a down side to the way I am approaching this in regards to SEO/ranking?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Robots.txt file setup properly which allows bots to crawl your website then the bots will crawl whatever it hits from that page on.  You can use google's webmaster tools to manually fetch pages it does not know about or you can upload a .txt file space separated with a list of links you would like google and other search engines to crawl.  From an SEO Stand point looking at this as a new website it will not matter if the pages are not strutured properly yet as you will have to build trust and authority overtime anyway.  From a professional SEO standpoint you do not want your site to launch when it is not ready to be indexed.  I would recommend setting up a robots.txt file or password protecting with htaccess until you are ready to actually launch your website with proper structure.  You can learn more on googles website about robots.txt here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961

Answer (score 1):

Perfect. Your approach is correct.

To answer your concerns, there is no way Search engines (SE) bots will be able to crawl your website without links to follow from the homepage. Hence, inner/hidden  pages will not get indexed.

What I like about what you are doing is that the homepage will get indexed. That's always my top recommendation. Also, I would suggest setting up search console, bing console, etc to make sure your homepage gets indexed.

There is not a SEO down side, what will happen is that you are skipping the so called sandbox period in which a website is not visible in search results, later on you will launch your complete website, swap the homepage and get indexed quickly, earning trust and authority with the new content added.